# Debugging jQuery error - Uncaught TypeError: this._addClass is not a function

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I'm having an issue with a specific page on a site I am helping with, i've spoken to the template developer and they are adamant that it is nothing to do with them and will not help (the page loads ok with the Beez3 template). 
Anyway, I am getting the following JS errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._addClass is not a function
at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (https://www.waterfrontwest.com/new/templates/incline/js/jquery/jquery-ui-addons.js:6:14102)
at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:5392)
at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWidget (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:7457)
at new e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:4975)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:6699)
at Function.each (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:2881)
at a.fn.init.each (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:846)
at a.fn.init.e.fn.(anonymous function) [as slider] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:6622)
at Object.app.buildSlider (https://www.waterfrontwest.com/new/components/com_iproperty/assets/advsearch/sliders.js:62:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (https://www.waterfrontwest.com/new/components/com_iproperty/assets/advsearch/sliders.js:19:28)
```

I have no idea where to start with trying to fix these? Would anybody be able to assist/advise on where to start? The page can be found [here](https://www.waterfrontwest.com/new/index.php/bc-waterfront-properties-for-sale-advanced-search-click-here).

Thank you in advance.
Regards
D

Comment: Deactivate the com_iproperty component and related moduls / plugin by the extension manager. Check if the propblem persists. I recommend to fix all the other console errors before. (http/https erros for example)

Comment: HI Dennis, I cannot do that - this page is part of that component, thus if I disable the component the page does not exist.

Comment: Then create a simple article page without the component loaded.

Comment: Hi Dennis thank you for your response, the problem is specific to this page....the jQuery errors to not appear on other pages.

Comment: Could you replace the jquery.ui.core.min.js with a full version of the jquery.ui? https://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert at this but have a couple of suggestions that might help.

**Load Order**

Currently, jQuery is loading before Google Maps and MooTools.

These three libraries seem to work best together when MooTools loads first, then jQuery and then Google Maps last.

You might be able to force MooTools to load first by adding this line high up in the HEAD section of the template index.php file:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
```

[jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy) can also help with loading the libraries in the right order and may be able to help with stopping MooTools loading if it is not needed.

**Updates**

Updating the template, third party extensions and Joomla to the latest versions might help reduce any conflicts.

Removing or disabling unused extensions might also help.

Comment: HI Neil, Thank you - I have tried your suggestion to add the line to the index.php of the template but this did not seem to have any affect on the load order. I had installed jQuery easy already and hashed around with the settings, again to no avail. I'll have to keep digging - this is frustrating.